# Where has my car gone?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I was driving my Zantorno; then suddenly I crashed into a river. So I took a taxi back to the garage; the car was not there.

I checked the Car Impound and it was not there, then I went back to the river it was not there either.

Comment: SIngle Player or online ?

Answer (score 4):

If it's Mutiplayer then most likely you have to call Mors Mutual Insurance from your phone, to get a replacement car for around $9000. It will be delivered to you in few seconds.

If, on the other hand, it was SinglePlayer, where you crashed your car in the water, then I believe it's gone and can't be recovered. Same happens if you explode it or loose it in anyway ...